# Jquery hover + position absolute = Problems in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm making a drop down menu and it works great in all modern browser but im not sure, it fails in IE, when i try to select the sub-elements of the submenu, it disappears.

This is the page: http://XXX/

and this is the JS code

```
$("nav li").hover(function(){
    $(".subnavi-wrapper", $(this)).show();
}, function(){
    $(".subnavi-wrapper", $(this)).hide();
});
```

EDIT: Apparently it's the margins on top of the dropdown which seem to activate the "mouseout" in IE! Aparently jQuery detects badly the area of the items with position absolute! :(

Comment: you can navigate the subpages selecting the top pages and selecting content from them, so its no problem.

Comment: Is that something you are adding later or something I have missed? You know it is fairly easy to create a drop down menu using just CSS. It would probably fix the issue you are having now as well.

Comment: actually I want to replace the "show" for "fadeIn" later. im just simpliying the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all because block "subnavi-wrapper" in Li element. You must remove DIV and try do it only by using Ul element. I made something like it here: http://www.muzykakoncerty.pl

here, something like this:

```
$('#menu > ul > li').each(function() {
    if($('ul', this).length > 0) {
        $(this).hover(
            function() {
                $('ul', this).show();
            },
            function() {
                $('ul', this).hide();
            }
        );
    }
});
```

and my menu HTML code is:

```
          <div id="menu">
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      <a href="index.html">wstęp</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="zespol-big-band.html">Big Band</a></li>
                          <li><a href="zespol-arti-sound-concert.html">Arti Sound Concert</a></li>
                          <li><a href="zespol-leszczynska-kapela-barokowa.html">Leszczyńska Kapela Barokowa</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <a href="#">zespoły</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="taniec-dancing-sisters.html">Dancing Sisters</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <a href="#">taniec</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="o-mnie.html">o mnie</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="kontakt.html">kontakt</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

EDIT:

so try it:

```
$('nav > ul > li').each(function() {
    if($('ul', this).length > 0) {
        $(this).hover(
            function() {
                $('ul', this).show();
            },
            function() {
                $('ul', this).hide();
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: What is it about the subnavi-wrapper? :S i use it because i want to leave 1 pixel line between the dropdown and the menu and I need that line to be an area container inside the LI

Comment: you can do it without div block. IE probably doesn't accept that because with DIV it is not continous list - it's something new for him (i guess)

Comment: to make 1px line just use CSS for ul inside li. margin-top: 1px;

Comment: @maverix: the problem with making margin-top: 1px is that the margin area would untrigger the "hover" of the LI :(

Comment: so edit background ;) add 1px on top transparent! that should do the trick :)

Comment: Ok, screw all I said. I removed the DIV and the 1px margin and the error PERSISTS! :(

Comment: I removed the DIV and the margin and the error is still there :(

Comment: i don't know, but it works and it's hand-made :P i edited my answer and posted code for you. just try...

Comment: then sorry but i have no idea... :/ as you see, for me it works just perfect. maybe something with CSS? try turn-off filters... i dont know... :(

Comment: Appears to be an issue of jquery detecting "hover" on subnavi when its got position:absolute :(

Answer (score 1):

What you have uses the [*multiple selector* selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) will show/hide both the `nav li` *and* the `.subnavi-wrapper`. I think you only need to toggle the `.subnavi-wrapper`

```
$("nav li").hover(function(){
        $(".subnavi-wrapper").show();
    }, function(){
        $(".subnavi-wrapper").hide();
    });
```

If you only want to show the `.subnavi-wrapper` under the current `li`:

```
$("nav li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".subnavi-wrapper").show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".subnavi-wrapper").hide();
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I hover a element from the main navigations all the submenus come down.

Comment: I've updated my answer to limit the show/hide to the relevant subnavi

Comment: @ezmilhouse - yes we do, it's linked in the question.

Comment: @marverix - no, the OP was using the *multiple selector* selector. I am finding descendants of the scoped element

Comment: @Dbugger in IE8, your current code is showing the dropdown under *Uber uns*

Comment: @adam the problem comes when you slide the mouse inside the dropdow. The dropwdown disappears.

Comment: @adam OP was not using the multiple selector selector. The comma is outside the selector. The OP is using a context on his selector (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1). Your solution is incorrect. OPs code looks ok, but without knowing his HTML it will be difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Dbugger maybe you should put this in the question then

Comment: @adam: its already written: " when i try to select the sub-elements of the submenu, it disappears."

Comment: @Rony: you can see the HTML in the page. The link is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// show
$("nav li").live('mouseover',function(){
    $(".subnavi-wrapper").show();
});

// hide
$("nav li").live('mouseout',function(){
    $(".subnavi-wrapper").hide();
});
```

Comment: `live` binds the event to all matching elements *now and in the future*. No elements are being dynamically added, so you don't need `live`